# How to use cv::warpPerspective for the perspective transformation?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to rectify images. I have point correspondences and I computed both of the matrices F1 and F2. After that, I want to rectify. following is my code

```
     cv::Mat F1(4,4, CV_64FC1);
     cv::Mat F2(4,4, CV_64FC1);

    CvMat* points1 = cvCreateMat(8,1,CV_64FC2);
CvMat* points2 = cvCreateMat(8,1,CV_64FC2);



    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
                cvSet2D(points1,i,0,cvScalar(gt[i].xL,gt[i].yL));
        cvSet2D(points2,i,0,cvScalar(gt[i].xR,gt[i].yR));
    }

    cv::Size size (imgL->width, imgL->height);
    cv::stereoRectifyUncalibrated(points1, points2, F, size, F1, F2);


IplImage* rectL = cvCreateImage(cvSize(imgL->width,imgL->height), imgL->depth, imgL->nChannels);


cv::warpPerspective(imgL, rectL , F1, size);


cvSaveImage("rectL.jpg", rectL);
```

The error is the following

```
    error: in passing argument 2 of ‘void cv::warpPerspective(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, cv::Size, int, int, const cv::Scalar&)’
```

And if I do create a CvMat as follows

```
    CvMat* rectified1 = cvCreateMat(imgL->width,imgL->height,imgL->depth);


    cv::warpPerspective(imgL, *rectified1, F1,size);


   cvSaveImage("rectified1.png", imgL);
```

Then the error is in saving the image. It say that this array is not recognized.

I am wondering if someone could please help me in this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cvMat` and `cv::Mat` are two different things. `cvMat` [is obsolete](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvmat#cvmat). If you convert everything to cv::Mat it should take care of your problem.